# In perl, what are these variables without sigils?

Tags: perl, class, variables

I'm trying to understand Higher Order Perl's Flat-File Database.

In package FlatDB, sub new, on page 141, he has the statement:

bless { FH => $fh, FIELDS => \@field, FIELDNUM => \%fieldnum,
          FIELDSEP => $FIELDSEP }  => $class;

where $class == FlatDB.

What are these variables (FH, FIELDNUM, etc.) without sigils? How can I print their values, find their types, or use them?

FlatDB appears to be some sort of hash of a hash, but all my attempts to print the values result in an error, eg:

```
printhash(\%fieldnum,"at37:\\%fieldnum=");
# prints the hash properly, BUT
printhash(FlatDB{FIELDNUM),"at38:FlatDB{FIELDNUM}=");
printhash(FlatDB->FIELDNUM,"at39:FlatDB->FIELDNUM=");
# print the error:
# Can't locate object method "FIELDNUM" via package "FlatDB"
```

Why does it think FIELDNUM is a method, when it is defined as a hash?

FYI: the printhash sub is:

```
sub printhash
 { my $href=shift;  # a REFERENCE to a hash
   my $msg=shift;   # a text message
   my %h = %{$href};
   my $len = keys %h;;
   print "\n$msg, length=$len";
   foreach my $k ( keys %h )
   { print "\nkey: $k, value: $h{$k}";  }
   print "\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're not variables.

They're keys in a blessed hash reference (i.e., [an object](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#An-Object-is-Simply-a-Data-Structure)). The "[fat comma](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator)" (`=>` operator) allows a bareword on the left side to be interpreted as a string if it starts with a letter or underscore and only contains alphanumeric characters and underscores. (This has nothing to do with objects, but you'll commonly see this syntax when initializing a hash or hash reference, or whenever someone is explicitly trying to indicate an association.)

To answer your question:

> Why does it think FIELDNUM is a method, when it is defined as a hash?

Because you're invoking it as a method. The syntax is close to the [dereference operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator), but not exactly the same. In fact, the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Invocation) even says something to this effect:

> Calling a method on an object is written as `$object->method`.
>
> The left hand side of the method invocation (or arrow) operator is the
>   object (or class name), and the right hand side is the method name.
>
> ```
> my $pod = File->new( 'perlobj.pod', $data );
> $pod->save();
> ```
>
> The `->` syntax is also used when dereferencing a reference. It looks
>   like the same operator, but these are two different operations.

And:

> "`->`" is an infix dereference operator, just as it is in C and C++.
>   If the right side is either a `[...]`, `{...}`, or a `(...)`
>   subscript, then the left side must be either a hard or symbolic
>   reference to an array, a hash, or a subroutine respectively. (Or
>   technically speaking, a location capable of holding a hard reference,
>   if it's an array or hash reference being used for assignment.) See
>   [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).
>
> Otherwise, the right side is a method name or a simple scalar variable
>   containing either the method name or a subroutine reference, and the
>   left side must be either an object (a blessed reference) or a class
>   name (that is, a package name). See [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

But really, what you probably want is an instance of the class, which would look something like this:

```
my $obj = FlatDB->new;
```

And then you can access the object members like so:

```
$obj->{FH};
@{$obj->{FIELDS}};
%{$obj->{FIELDNUM}};
$obj->{FIELDSEP};
```

But you shouldn't because of encapsulation. Unfortunately, explaining that and other OOP principles is outside the scope of this answer.